# how to apply css on td where css class for each column is separate in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am displaying table using ng- repeat.This table has columns where each column has different css class.
How can I apply the styling.

```
<td  class="abcCell"
            ng-repeat="(key, value)  in Rows"
            ng-class= "clasTobeGeneratedDynamically"
            ng-click="onclick(rowId)">
```

Comment: where the exact class name stored?

Comment: the class name are as follows:
column1
column2
column3
--------
1,2,3 are columnids coming as key of the rows
columnIds are not necessarily in sequence.

Comment: I mean, you have an array `Rows`, you iterating through it. And each item there have class name what should be used, or .. ?

Comment: yes somewhat like it.

Answer (score 0):

Continue form comments:

I see at least two options here:

1) let's say that every item in `Rows` array have `className` field. In this case just adding `class="{{key.className}}"` will work.

```
<td  class="abcCell {{key.className}}"
            ng-repeat="(key, value)  in Rows"
            ng-class= "clasTobeGeneratedDynamically"
            ng-click="onclick(rowId)">
```

2) you have pre-defined class names for each item in `Rows` (depending on presence of some field, or value of something). Then you'll need to use `ng-class`:

```
<td  class="abcCell"
                ng-repeat="(key, value)  in Rows"
                ng-class= "clasTobeGeneratedDynamically"
                ng-click="onclick(rowId)"
                ng-class="{class1 : key.field1}">
```

or

```
<td  class="abcCell"
                ng-repeat="(key, value)  in Rows"
                ng-class= "clasTobeGeneratedDynamically"
                ng-click="onclick(rowId)"
                ng-class="{class1 : key.field == 'value1'}">
```

Does anything here matches your case?